# Typescript custom types: Replace undefined-type with string-type

Tags: typescript, types, undefined, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

*UndefinedAsString* does exactly what I want, but *UndefinedAsString2* does not convert undefined to strings. The question is why?

```
type UndefinedAsString<T> = T extends undefined ? string : T;

const y: UndefinedAsString<object[] | undefined> = 'test'; // ok
const x: UndefinedAsString<object[]> = 'test'; // fails

type UndefinedAsString2<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends undefined ? string : T[K];
};
const z: UndefinedAsString2<{ x: object[] | undefined }> = { x: 'test' }; // fails
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does `UndefinedAsString` work? Because of [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). Each element of the union `object[] | undefined` will be distributed individually to `UndefinedAsString`. The comparison to `undefined` works because `T` is always a single type which is either `undefined` or not.

---

Why doesn't `UndefinedAsString2` work? Distribution does not take place here. So the union `object[] | undefined` will be checked for extending `undefined` which is false. You need to switch the order around here to check if `undefined` extends `T[K]`.

```
type UndefinedAsString2<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: undefined extends T[K] ? string : T[K];
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgEwgMwJZwggggZwMrABO6A5gDwAqAfFALxQVQQAewEiOUAroiuplAD8UHEVJQAXAwDcAKFkBjAPZxRUEFPhI0GbPjFxySgEYArCAuABtALpQAPt147MNegHI2o99KgB6PyglAGtFFTVmTWd%20PQJiQzITc0tbNyhPCG9fAKhkAENUABsceVBIBgBGOlho3Vw40kSzC2s7Rx5tGKpS8GgtPjr9eJIAJkomVnYETgAlCyVCBDJRYYAaKDy4ECo0gG9ZKCgrAGkodChgiBAlZAYbKQ6BgRY2DgYTu2EV8SkKD7kAL5yWRlaAUEbVfouWIGUZkXZQSJBZopNpOTq6KAA7phVTAKAALyiGMw9VhYwRSKSLVsDnRTwQWL2iKkGW8WOygXyRRwQA)